# Dds delete_contained_entities no source file named A.cpp in a shared library

Tags: c++, function, file, shared, data-distribution-service

I get Dds delete_contained_entities error, when i check debugger console it says "no source file named A.cpp" in my shared library. Whats the problem, can someone help pls

Comment: Which DDS implementation are you using?

Comment: Also, what error is returned from the delete_contained_entities() call?